# npm create-react-app myapp gives error Command failed: create-react-app spawn EPERM

Tags: reactjs

Months ago, on my home PC I installed nodejs, react, etc., and got various tutorial sample projects working.
Now I’m remoting to my up-to-date Windows 10 work PC to install everything.

I’ve done the setup steps from the Traversy Media React Crash Course tutorial (5 stars), also just now, to double-check, watched the 1-minute video and reviewed the simple instructions at   https://www.techomoro.com/how-to-install-and-setup-a-react-app-on-windows-10/  .

So I’ve installed nodejs from https://nodejs.org/en  and downloaded react-0.14.3.zip (but there’s not an .msi installer, just a build folder and an examples folder… am I forgetting or missing something?)

Installed create-react-app globally:
PS C:\users\molin\dev\myapp> npm install -g create-react-app
…which spewed out…
C:\Users\molin\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\molin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
[+ sign] create-react-app@4.0.1 updated 1 package in 7.639s

When I’m a level above the myapp folder and do either of these:
npx create-react-app .
npx create-react-app myapp
…or if I’m in the myapp folder and do either of these:
npx create-react-app myapp
npx create-react-app .

… I get the error:
Command failed: create-react-app spawn EPERM

Per a suggestion on a board, I ran this and retried, but no joy.
npm cache clean --force
I even rebooted and tried again.

No events show on the Window Event viewer.
Is this a permissions error on my work PC?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

### Reinstall react app globally
`npm i -g create-react-app`

Recreate your app -
`create-react-app` 
(maybe this will help)

Comment: Thanks @z-Amiryan... but no joy.  It said "Updated 1 package in 7.123 seconds", but when I cd to the myapp folder and retried npx create-react-app . it again says "command failed: create-react-app spawn EPERM".

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, jeez. In case this helps someone...

- Opened VS Code; Undoubtedly didn't need to do this, but did File >
- Open the folder myapp (which contained nothing yet)
- Opened the VS Code terminal, cd .. to go a level up above the myapp folder;
- npx create-react-app myappNEW , IOW a folder that didn't exist yet.

If I did that last command for "myapp", it gave the spawn error.

I had typed the following, but then tried it and it failed, so this is not the case:  Conceivably, when doing this from the powershell, I didn't try npx (rather than npm) with a non-existent folder name.

Comment: The saga continues... all of that worked twice, with those instances separated and trailed by lots and lots of abject failure. So I followed someone's advice and downloaded & installed Yarn and used the Yarn commands to create the React app. Sheesh.

Answer (score 0):

No need for any other package install in your PC or System.

1. [Install node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node)

> npm i node

2. create project

> **npx create-react-app project_name --template all**

Comment: Hi @Chaurasia, I just now noticed your reply. I will give your npx syntax a try.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try these commands on your terminal:-**

```
npx create-react-app my-app

cd my-app

npm start
```

**I hope this will help you out.**

*You can also visit* https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html *for your reference.*

Comment: Thanks @sc, I'll try this when I get back to React, of course my job changed direction again.